# Salir de una función sin terminar todo el proceso main en c++

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo una libería de tensores en C++, quiero que cuando quieras hacer operaciones con distintas dimensiones de un mensaje que no se puede hacer la operación y seguir con las demas funciones que llamo en el main. Esta es la función

```
template<typename T>
Tensor<T> Tensor<T>::operator*(const Tensor<T> &tensor2){

if(t_ranks != tensor2.t_ranks || t_rows != tensor2.t_rows || t_cols !=tensor2.t_cols){
    std::cout << "No se puede efectuar la operación, revisa las dimensiones de los tensores" << std::endl;  
    exit(1);
}


Tensor<T> tensor(tensor2.t_ranks, tensor2.t_rows,tensor2.t_cols);
const auto result = tensor.t_data.get();

for(int i=0; i < tensor2.t_ranks* tensor2.t_rows*tensor2.t_cols; i++){
    result[i] = t_data.get()[i]*tensor2.t_data.get()[i];}

return tensor;
}
```

en el main la mando a llamar, así

```
Tensor<double> p1 = a*b; //aquí manda el mensaje de que no se puede proceder pero ejecuta las siguientes dos lineas 
cout << "El reshape de a solo se puede hacer si se ingresa las dimensiones adecuadas, si tratamos de cambiar ranks=4,rows=1 y cols= 2 hay un error"<< endl;
Tensor<double> m(a,4,1,2);
```

¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: exit(0) lo que hace es finalizar la aplicación, lo que tienes que hacer es un return, saldrá de la función mas no de la aplicación, recuerda que la funcion retornar un tipo de dato tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con exit lo que haces es abortar el programa, como la función devuelve un tensor declárate un tensor auxiliar (aux por ejemplo) en el if e inicializalo con valores inválidos (esto no es necesario pero sí recomendable por si se intenta usar) y cambia el exit por return aux;

Comment: ¿Cómo se declararía el tensor auxiliar? Por favor, añade algo de código que ilustre la solución.